# What do I do about quadricep pain?

Tags: squats, pain, stronglifts, quads

Over the last few weeks, as the weight on my squats has gotten heavier I've been noticing some pain in my quadricep. Not the normal muscle soreness, it's a little sharper and feels "deeper" in the muscle. It also seems to go horizontally across the quadricep.

Looking up a muscle diagram it seems to be right around where the dot for Rectus Femoris is in this diagram:

[image]

Maybe just a touch lower, possibly where it starts turning into tendon. (Kind of hard to pinpoint, sorry.)

I found this article talking about Rectus Femoris pain: http://www.triggerpointtherapist.com/blog/knee-pain-trigger-points/rectus-femoris-trigger-point-quadriceps/

And it talks about how tight calves (specifically the soleus muscle) can cause you to overcompensate using your quads when doing squats. My calves are super tight and that includes the soleus so... probably onto something there. The only caveat is I'm not getting the knee pain as they describe it, or at the same times (they say it's worse at night.)

What I do get is it will "ping" sometimes when standing up from a seated position, or climbing a stair. Between sets of squats my quads feel really, really tight almost like the muscle is clenching around that spot. That said, it doesn't seem to interfere with me actually doing the squats at all and I've been able to continue increasing the weight just fine.

So what do I do about it? The article suggests a trigger point massage but it also seems to be selling a book for it so...

Would just stretching more help? I've been considering some yoga between lifting days anyway.

Should I rest the muscle longer to let it heal? The longest I've rested since noticing this is 3 days... I'd rather not skip too many workouts and lose momentum.

Comment: Does a wider stance change anything while doing squats? Are you too far over your foot with your knees when doing them? Are you squating barefooted or with a raised heel? If you have tried different variants, and still feeling the problems you should consult a doc.

Comment: @mitro Hard to tell about the stance since it doesn't bother me while actually doing the squat. I get my heel on the ground but have to stretch beforehand to make that happen.

Comment: I had some similar issues that went away through widening my stance a little more doing gobblet squats as warm-up. I do some fascial release with a foam roller prior exercising now regurarily. .. it may help you too. In any case it would be good to consult a doc to exclude an injury.